# Why are ssh keys not present in the folder?

Tags: ssh

I have experimented with creating a SSH key as follows:

[image: SSH key generation]

But as I look in the directory using PowerShell, I cannot find any files. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

[image: Cannot locate SSH keys]

Note: I have censored my username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file should be in the `C:\Users\your-username` folder.

After you execute `ssh-keygen`, it asked you where you wanted to save your key, and it told you that the default location would be `C:\Users\your-username/.ssh/id_ed25519`, but you specified `afdsaf` instead without giving absolute path.  So the resulting key would be `C:\Users\your-username\afdsaf`.

Comment: My apologies for my rookie mistake. Thank you for your clear answer.